# How can I group by a field emitted events?

Tags: rx-java2

I have a class User:

```
class User {
  String companyId;
}
```

and a class Company:

```
class Company {
    String id;
    List<User> users;
}
```

I need to "group" the Users emitted by a `Observable<User>` by company and return a `Observable<Company>`. I have this:

```
public Observable<Company> getCompanies(Observable<User> users) {
    return users.distinct(new Func1<User, String>(){
        @Override
        public String call(User user) {
            return user.companyId;
        }
    }).map(new Func1<User, Company>(){
         @Override
         public Company call(User user) {
             return new Company(user.companyId);
         }
    });
}
```

It works but it's just getting distinct users by companyId. I need to set the `List<User>` of each company. Is there any operator I can use to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! There is a `groupBy` operator -.-"

```
public Observable<Company> getCompanies(Observable<User> users) {
    return users.groupBy(new Func1<User, String>(){
        @Override
        public String call(User user) {
            return user.companyId;
        }
    }).flatMap(new Func1<GroupedObservable<String, User>, Observable<List<User>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<List<User>> call(GroupedObservable<String, User> grouped) {
                    return grouped.toList();
                }
            }, new Func2<GroupedObservable<String, User>, List<User>, Company>() {
                @Override
                public Company call(GroupedObservable<String, User> grouped, List<User> users) {
                    return new Company(grouped.getKey(), users);
                }
            });
```